# C++ - change the cursor in an X Window

Tags: c++, linux, x11, mouse-cursor

I thought this would be easy to find, but a google search has been very unhelpful. Is there a simple api to change the mouse cursor in your X window? (I know in windows you can just call "SetCursor")

Comment: Have you looked at `man Xcursor`?

Comment: I started reading that, but it's still very hard to get good info. All I want to do is something like "SetCursor(hand)" and "SetCursor(arrow)". Is there an example on how to do this somewhere?

Comment: I would not touch X directly. Why not Qt, WX, Gtk or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>

/* ... */

Cursor c;

c = XCreateFontCursor(dpy, XC_xterm); 
XDefineCursor(dpy, w, c);
```

Where dpy is your display, w is your window and XC_xterm is a constant defining the shape of your cursor. Here's [a list of available cursor shape](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/), along with images.

Comment: but these constants will only get you the ugly icons from the "cursor" font. How do you get the WM default icons with drop shadows and everything?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the equivalent of a SetCursor call is `XDefineCursor`. You can get a `Cursor` id by calling `XCreateFontCursor` and passing in one of the shapes from `X11/cursorfont.h`.

Comment: There's more details on these at http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/pixmap-and-cursor/cursor.html