# Change mouse cursor in C++ application

Tags: c++, graphics

I am building an application using a framework that uses `OpenGL, GLEW, GLUT, libtess2 and cairo` for graphics, and making windows and animaton using the same. I have a requirement to change the mouse cursor and was looking for a way to do this in C++ application.

I'm currently developing on Unix (Ubuntu 12.10), Code::Blocks IDE and the project properties are:

Type: Console Application

Build application for: All platforms

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583746/c-change-the-cursor-in-an-x-window for a description of how to change the cursor with X11.